# Error passing ArrayList<Object> to another activity - Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: java, android, serialization, parcelable

I try to pass an `ArrayList<DatosVenta>` to another `Activity` but i have this problem: Parcelable encountered `IOException` writing serializable object (name = com.madmvx.proyectou.Models.ModelUtils.DatosVenta)
My class `DatosVenta` implements `Serializable`

i tried with `Parcelable` but i don't get nothing in the other `Activity`
i get null

```
public class DatosVenta implements Serializable {
Vendedor vendedor;
String nombreCliente, gestionRealizada, observaciones, zona, quienAtiende, fecha;

public DatosVenta(Vendedor vendedor, String nombreCliente, String gestionRealizada, String observaciones, String zona, String fecha, String quienAtiende) {
    this.vendedor = vendedor;
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    this.gestionRealizada = gestionRealizada;
    this.observaciones = observaciones;
    this.zona = zona;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.quienAtiende = quienAtiende;
    this.zona = zona;
}

public DatosVenta() {

}


public String getQuienAtiende() {
    return quienAtiende;
}

public void setQuienAtiende(String quienAtiende) {
    this.quienAtiende = quienAtiende;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public Vendedor getVendedor() {
    return vendedor;
}

public void setVendedor(Vendedor vendedor) {
    this.vendedor = vendedor;
}

public String getNombreCliente() {
    return nombreCliente;
}

public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
}

public String getGestionRealizada() {
    return gestionRealizada;
}

public void setGestionRealizada(String gestionRealizada) {
    this.gestionRealizada = gestionRealizada;
}

public String getObservaciones() {
    return observaciones;
}

public void setObservaciones(String observaciones) {
    this.observaciones = observaciones;
}

public String getZona() {
    return zona;
}

public void setZona(String zona) {
    this.zona = zona;
}
```

}

```
if(!datosVentaList.isEmpty() && datosVentaList != null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AdminShowRuterosActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("datosVentaList",datosVentaList);
                startActivity(intent);
                dismiss();
            }else{
                Log.d("LISTA<>", "No hay datos");
                dismiss();
            }
```

in my **AdminShowRuterosActivity.class**

```
        datosVentaArrayList = (ArrayList<DatosVenta>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("datosVentaList");
```

Comment: Vendedor in this class you need to implements Serializable.

Comment: Oh yeah, I will try it, thanks